# (Не)обязательно: слитно или раздельно?

Tags: слитно-раздельно

Те бренды, которые популярны у нас, совсем необязательно будут столь же актуальны...

Answer (score 6):

Слово *совсем* может иметь значение, близкое к *очень* (пишем слитно с *не*),а может быть синонимично слову *вовсе* (пишем с *не* раздельно). В данном предложении, на мой взгляд, *совсем не* синонимично *вовсе не*, а значит пишем раздельно.

Answer (score 2):

«Совсем»  может являться наречием со значением «совершенно» - получается «совершенно необязательно». «Совсем» может иметь  значение «ни в какой степени, нисколько» перед  частицей НЕ - получается  «совсем не обязательно», отнюдь не обязательно». Следовательно,  оба варианта возможны (здесь авторское решение), но по смыслу больше подходит отрицание, причем оно относится не к слову, а к словосочетанию в целом: обязательно будут актуальны – (совсем не) обязательно будут актуальны. Кроме отрицания предполагаемого события, при раздельном написании НЕ автор имеет возможность выделить "совсем не обязательно" с помощью логического ударения, которое характерно для подобных конструкций.

Answer (score 0):

В данном предложении надо писать слитно. Как в примере "Приходить на вечеринку совсем необязательно" . А вот при противопоставлении этого слова другому, надо писать раздельно. Например, "Укажи в объявлении, что соблюдать дресс-код не обязательно, но желательно."  Слово "совсем" здесь никакого отношения к слову "очень" не имеет. А вообще всё, предложенное для разбора предложение со словом "совсем", носит просторечный, а не литературный оттенок. Потому и разбор так затруднен.